# How to handle different units in dialogs?

Tags: c++, dialog

Dialogs are used to input user data. For convenience, several unit options (like m, km, inch) for user data are provided, where users can choose a proper one. Any good way or existing library to handle different units in dialog code? For example

```
Length (m): _______
```

if unit m is chosen, and

```
Length (km): _________
```

if unit km is chosen. The final input will all convert to a standard unit like MKS unit.

Comment: Is this about the design of the interface or internal logic?

Comment: I am looking for a good (small) architecture to do it. I think I need a class named `Unit` and ....